# Recovering partitioning information from block devices

Tags: linux, partition, ntfs

I recently overwrote ~100MB from the beginning of my 1TB external hdd using the dd command. This means my partition tables have likely been lost. fdisk -l shows no partition information.

However since I actually had my drive mounted while issuing the dd command, the data on the drive (all partitions) can be accesed with the file explorer. The external hdd is still connected to the computer. This leads me to believe that the partition table can be recovered.

Searches on this topic recommend data recovery tools that can restore the partition table, but these options assume the drive has been disconnected from the computer.

Looking at /proc/partitions gives the size of each block device, but not their offsets in sectors.

I assume that since i can view the file structure in nautilus, the partition offsets must be known. Is there a way to expose this information?

Comment: Just don't shut down your computer  ;'D. That's a really difficult problem. Isn't the partition table saved additionally in RAM?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get partition information from `/sys`, precisely from `/sys/block/<disk>/<partition>/{start,size}`.

This shell function may help you::

```
print_partitions()
{
    local disk="$1"
    local part
    local template="%-6s %16s %16s %16s\n"

    printf "$template" Part. "First sector" "Last sector" "# sectors"
    for part in "/sys/block/$disk/"sd*; do
        st="$(cat "$part/start")"
        sz="$(cat "$part/size")"
        end=$((st + sz - 1))
        printf "$template" "${part##*/}" "$st" "$end" "$sz"
    done
}
```

Usage:

```
$ print_partitions sdd
Part.      First sector      Last sector        # sectors
sdd1               2048          2099199          2097152
sdd3            2099200       3907029167       3904929968
```

Note: sectors here are 512 byte sectors.

For a full dump of your partitions:

```
for disk in /sys/block/sd*; do
    print_partitions "${disk##*/}"
    echo
done
```

Note that you may also have overwritten precious information at the beginning of the first partition, like an ext superblock, but this is another <s>story</s> question.

Comment: be sure to only execute the function definition from the cmd-line (don't save it as a file until you resolve your partition problem.) Good luck.

Comment: Thanks. I was able to get the offsets and sizes of the partitions from /sys/block/sdX. After partitioning the drive correctly with fdisk, I restored the NTFS boot sector with TestDisk. Then, I ran chkdsk in Windows, which was able to restore the NTFS filesystem with a large majority of files still present.

Comment: @bananasplits Wow, you are lucky :)

Comment: Haha, actually the reason why i stopped dd at 100MB of data written is because I realized I still had the drive mounted so I wanted to unmount it before continuing. Then I checked the mount points and saw that I wrote to the wrong device! It was a close call.

Comment: @bananasplits still you are quite lucky that 100MB didn't overwrite any important MFT entry.